# How best to store hashmap in sqlite database

Tags: c++, sqlite, hashmap

I have a hashmap defined as follows:

- Key = Month of year;
- Value = Another hashmap, where:

  - Key = Day of month;
  - Value = The rainfall.

What is the best way to store such a hashmap in a database?

Please also note that I will be storing many of these hashmaps (representing multiple experimental runs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a table with tree columns:

```
Month, Day, Rainfall
```

using (Month,Day) as primary key if values are unique, Otherwise you can use an ID.

More, you could use only two columns:

```
Date, Rainfall
```

Generally, you need to reproduce the hashmap key-value pair into a table, which is more or less similar:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3

"Month1" "day1" "rainfall1"
"Month1" "day2" "rainfall2"
    .       .        .
    .       .        .
    .       .        .
"MonthN" "dayM" "rainfallX"
```